# How to reduce code clutter in this function?

Tags: ocaml

The function `tally` below is really simple: it takes a string `s` as argument, splits it on non-alphanumeric characters, and tallies the numbers of the resulting "words", case-insensitively.

```
open Core.Std

let tally s =
  let get m k =
    match Map.find m k with
    | None   -> 0
    | Some n -> n
  in

  let upd m k = Map.add m ~key:k ~data:(1 + get m k) in

  let re = Str.regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" in
  let ws = List.map (Str.split re s) ~f:String.lowercase in

  List.fold_left ws ~init:String.Map.empty ~f:upd
```

I think this function is harder to read than it should be due to clutter.  I wish I could write something closer to this (where I've indulged in some "fantasy syntax"):

```
(* NOT VALID SYNTAX -- DO NOT COPY !!! *)

open Core.Std

let tally s =

  let get m k =
        match find m k with
        | None   -> 0
        | Some n -> n ,

      upd m k = add m k (1 + get m k) ,

      re = regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" ,
      ws = map (split re s) lowercase 

  in fold_left ws empty upd
```

The changes I did above fall primarily into three groups:

1. get rid of the repeated `let ... in`'s, consolidated all the bindings (into a `,`-separated sequence; this, AFAIK, is not valid OCaml);
2. got rid of the `~foo:`-type noise in function calls;
3. got rid of the prefixes `Str.`, `List.`, etc.

Can I achieve similar effects using valid OCaml syntax?

Comment: fyi, there is a `Map.change` that is a more natural choice for updating entries in your map: `let update m k = String.Map.change m k (function None -> Some 1 | Some n -> Some (n+1))`

Comment: @ivg: thanks!  btw, why `Some 1 | ... Some (n+1)`, and not just `1 | ... (n+1)`?  i've seen functions like this one before (i.e. that return *only* `Some`'s), but i can't see the rationale for them.

Comment: `change key f` is a swiss-knife function. Its semantics is the following: if key is not present, then `f` is called with `None`, otherwise it is called with `Some v`, where `v` is a value bound to `key`. If function `f` returns `Some u`, the key would be rebound to `u`, if it returns `None` the the `key` will be removed (if it exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readability is difficult to achieve, it highly depends on the reader's abilities and familiarity with the code. I'll focus simply on the syntax transformations, but you could perhaps refactor the code in a more compact form, if this is what you are really looking for.

To remove the module qualifiers, simply open them beforehand:

```
open Str 
open Map
open List
```

You must open them in that order to make sure the `List` values you are using there are still reachable, and not scope-overridden by the  `Map` ones.

For labelled parameters, you may omit the labels if for each function call you provide all the parameters of the function in the function signature order.

To reduce the number of `let...in` constructs, you have several options:

1. Use a set of rec definitions:

   ```
   let tally s =
     let rec get m k =
        match find m k with
        | None   -> 0
        | Some n -> n

     and upd m k = add  m k (1 + get m k)

     and re = regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" 
     and ws = map lowercase (split re s)

   in fold_left ws empty upd
   ```
2. Make multiple definitions at once:

   ```
   let tally s =
     let get, upd, ws =
       let  re = regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"  in
       fun m k ->
        match find m k with
        | None   -> 0
        | Some n -> n,
     fun g m k -> add  m k (1 + g m k),
     map lowercase (split re s)

   in fold_left ws empty (upd get)
   ```
3. Use a module to group your definitions:

   ```
   let tally s =
     let module M = struct 
       let get m k =
         match find m k with
         | None   -> 0
         | Some n -> n

       let upd m k = add m k (1 + get m k)

       let re = regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" 
       let ws = map lowercase (split re s)

   end in fold_left ws empty M.upd
   ```

The later is reminiscent of the Sml syntax, and *perhaps* better suited to proper optimization by the compiler, but it only get rid of the `in` keywords.

Please note that since I am not familiar with the Core Api, I might have written incorrect code.

Comment: for the first option you do not need indeed to make your binds recursive, i.e., `let x = 2 and y = 3` still works, and is much cleaner.

Comment: @ivg actually You're quite right: I could've untied the definitions as I did in 2nd option, and remove the `rec` binding completely! I would still have 2 let scopes though, one for the regexp and one for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sequence of computations on the same value, then in OCaml there is a `|>` operator, that takes a value from the left, and applies in to the function on the right. This can help you to "get rid of" `let` and `in`. What concerning labeled arguments, then you can get rid of them by falling back to a vanilla standard library, and make your code smaller, but less readable. Anyway, there is a small piece of sugar with labeled arguments, you can always write `f ~key ~data` instead of `f ~key:key ~data:data`. And, finally, module names can be removed either by local open syntax (`let open List in ...`) or by locally shorcutting it to a smaller names (`let module L = List in`).

Anyway, I would like to show you a code, that contains less clutter, to my opinion:

```
open Core.Std
open Re2.Std
open Re2.Infix
module Words = String.Map

let tally s =
  Re2.split ~/"\\PL" s |>
  List.map ~f:(fun s -> String.uppercase s, ()) |>
  Words.of_alist_multi |>
  Words.map ~f:List.length
```

Comment: fwiw, when i first started with ocaml i was annoyed at the chains of let..in as well. it seems to be the common idiom. i now filter it out mentally. the (|>) piping style saves you the let..in but often it requires using explicitly the labeled arguments to have them in the right order for (|>).